# How to and why to use Salesforce and Zksforce for iOS development

Tags: ios, ipad, api, cloud, salesforce

I'm developing a project for the iPad. My project is for a medical representatives. I need to populate their appointments, samples sold, to be delivered samples, etc.

I have to work with Cloud interface. For this I have got 2 words which I have to work with.

1. SalesForce
2. ZKSForce

I can see documentation about how to use this. But I want to know what is this? What is the purpose of using this.

Why to use SalesForce? Is ZKSForce a free library? Is there any other library apart from ZKSForce?

I need information about these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zkSforce](https://github.com/superfell/zksforce) is an open source cocoa library that accesses the salesforce.com SOAP api, You could use that or you could use the [iOS Mobile SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) which uses the salesforce.com REST api.